# Creating custom dictionary from two lists

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have following two python lists.

```
prob_tokens = ['119', '120', '123', '1234', '12345']

complete_tokens = ['112', '120', '121', '123', '1233', '1234', '1235', '12345']

min_len_sec_list = 3
max_len_sec_list = 5
```

I want to create a dictionary with elements from first list as keys and with following constraints :

1. if key does not exists in second list then the value will be `False`.
2. if key exists in second list with variants then the value will be `False`.

Eg:

(i) while checking `123`, if `1234`, `12345` exists (`123*`) in second list then value of `123` will be `False`.

(ii). Similarly while checking `1234`, if `12345` exists (`1234*`) then value will be `False`.

Here `*` will be `[0-9]{(max_len-len_token)}`

3. if key exists in second list with no variants then value will be `True`.

OUTPUT :

`final_token_dict`

```
{'119': False,'120': True, '123': False, '1234': False, '12345': True}
```

Can I get any suggestions on how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: So, what did you actually try?

Comment: "Here * will be [0-9]{(max_len-len_token)}" Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: I was not aware of startswith() function, I was trying many alternatives.  Basically I was checking, if 123 is my token and max_len is 5, then first whether 123 is present or not, if it is present any of four digit token startswith 123(such as 1230,1231,...,1239) or not, then again any five digit token starts with 123 or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a custom function with a dictionary comprehension:

```
prob_tokens = ['119', '120', '123', '1234', '12345']
complete_tokens = ['112', '120', '121', '123', '1233', '1234', '1235', '12345']

def mapper(val, ref_list):
    if any(x.startswith(val) and (len(x) > len(val)) for x in ref_list):
        return False
    if val in ref_list:
        return True
    return False

res = {i: mapper(i, complete_tokens) for i in prob_tokens}

print(res)

{'119': False, '120': True, '123': False, '1234': False, '12345': True}
```

If the number of characters criterion is important to you, you can adjust your logic accordingly using chained comparisons and an additional input:

```
def mapper(val, ref_list, max_len):
    if any(x.startswith(val) and (0 < (len(x) - len(val)) <= max_len) for x in ref_list):
        return False
    if val in ref_list:
        return True
    return False

min_len_sec_list = 3
max_len_sec_list = 5

add_lens = max_len_sec_list - min_len_sec_list

res = {i: mapper(i, complete_tokens, add_lens) for i in prob_tokens}
```

Comment: sort lists first to make faster as well, actually I guess that doesn't matter since you have to look through all values to see if any other token starts with the same prefix

Comment: exactly @aws_apprentice . But I will try with sorted list as well to check the performance. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your list into a [Trie, or Prefix Tree, structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), then check whether any of the keys is a prefix in that Trie. This will be faster than checking whether its a prefix of each element in the list individually. More specifically, if you have `k` elements in your `prob_tokens` list, and `n` elements in `complete_tokens`, then this will make only O(n+k), whereas checking each pair is O(n*k).<sup>1</sup>

```
def make_trie(lst):
    trie = {}
    for key in lst:
        t = trie
        for c in key:
            t = t.setdefault(c, {})
    return trie

def check_trie(trie, key):
    for c in key:
        trie = trie.get(c, None)
        if trie is None: return False # not in trie
        if trie == {}: return True    # leaf in trie
    return False  # in trie, but not a leaf

prob_tokens = ['119', '120', '123', '1234', '12345']
complete_tokens = ['112', '120', '121', '123', '1233', '1234', '1235', '12345']

trie = make_trie(complete_tokens)
# {'1': {'1': {'2': {}}, '2': {'0': {}, '1': {}, '3': {'3': {}, '4': {'5': {}}, '5': {}}}}}
res = {key: check_trie(trie, key) for key in prob_tokens}
# {'119': False, '120': True, '123': False, '1234': False, '12345': True}
```

<sup>1)</sup> Actually, the average length of the keys also is a factor, but it is so in both approaches.

Comment: Nice! Is there a good way to consider the "maximum number of characters" criterion OP seems to have?

Comment: @jpp To be honest, I did not really understand that part. If you did, can you explain?

Comment: Rereading, you're right, it's not *perfectly* clear. I've included in my interpretation at the end of my answer.

Comment: @jpp Since for my case, I need only those tokens which are present in second list and with no variants, I can filter out all tokens that are not in range of min_len and max_len. So both of the solution mentioned by you as well as by tobias_k works great for me.

Answer (score 3):

This might be another alternative

```
import re

prob_tokens = ['119', '120', '123', '1234', '12345']

complete_tokens = ['112', '120', '121', '123', '1233', '1234', '1235', '12345']

dictionary = dict()
for tok in prob_tokens:
    if tok not in complete_tokens or any([bool(re.compile(r'^%s\d+'%tok).search(tok2)) for tok2 in complete_tokens]):
        dictionary[tok] = False
    else:
        dictionary[tok] = True

print(dictionary)`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any`:

```
a = ['119', '120', '123', '1234', '12345']
b = ['112', '120', '121', '123', '1233', '1234', '1235', '12345']
new_d = {c:c in b and not any(i.startswith(c) and len(c) < len(i) for i in b) for c in a}
```

Output:

```
{'120': True, '1234': False, '119': False, '123': False, '12345': True}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could also try something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

prob_tokens = ['119', '120', '123', '1234', '12345']

complete_tokens = ['112', '120', '121', '123', '1233', '1234', '1235', '12345']

result = {}
for token in prob_tokens:
    token_len = len(token)

    # Create counts of prefix lengths
    counts = Counter(c[:token_len] for c in complete_tokens)

    # Set True if only one prefix found, else False
    result[token] = counts[token] == 1

print(result)
```

Which Outputs:

```
{'119': False, '120': True, '123': False, '1234': False, '12345': True}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a normal dict comprehension with the value being `True` if sum of number of elements in  `complete_tokens` that begins with the specified key is 1, would do the job

```
prob_tokens = ['119', '120', '123', '1234', '12345']
complete_tokens = ['112', '120', '121', '123', '1233', '1234', '1235', '12345']

res = {elem:sum(v.startswith(elem) for v in complete_tokens)==1 for elem in prob_tokens}
print (res)
```

**Output**

```
{'119': False, '120': True, '123': False, '1234': False, '12345': True}
```

For better efficiency, you can convert `complete_tokens` as a set and then use `any` instead of checking each and every element

```
complete_tokens_set = set(complete_tokens)
res = {elem:elem in complete_tokens_set and not any(v!=elem and v.startswith(elem) for v in complete_tokens_set) for elem in prob_tokens}
```